# Is there any cross-references mechanism in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

One should think the title of this post self-explanatory: I would like to generate a table of all variable names and references inside a Netbeans project.

Is there a means I can do this?

**I am mainly concerned with javascript.**

*By 'cross-reference' I mean a way to collect all names of variables and display in a list, along with those names, all places where the said variables are used. The term 'variables' also includes names of functions, of course.*

Ideally the list generated could be exported in some format for ulterior use.

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: @merlin2011 — I have just edited my post according to your question.

Comment: by cross-reference do you mean a has-type-relation or do you want to reference actual values of a variable ?

Comment: @ferhlich — I mean a list of the names of all variables, including the names of methods/functions where these variables are defined/used.